# How to calculate percentages of specific groups or factors within an R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

Hello I am fairly new to R and coding in general and couldn't seem to find a solution to the current problem I am having. I currently have a dataset that looks something along the lines of this:

| Passage Name | Guild | Passage yes/no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Rheophilic | 1 |
| A | Eurytopic | 1 |
| A | Eurytopic | 1 |
| A | N/A | 0 |
| A | Eurytopic | 1 |
| A | Rheophilic | 1 |
| A | Eurytopic | 1 |
| A | Rheophilic | 0 |
| A | Rheophilic | 1 |
| B | Eurytopic | 1 |
| B | Eurytopic | 1 |
| B | Eurytopic | 0 |
| B | Eurytopic | 1 |
| B | Eurytopic | 1 |
| B | Eurytopic | 1 |
| B | Rheophilic | 1 |
| B | Limnophilic | 1 |
| B | Limnophilic | 0 |

Here I want to calculate the percentage of passage per Passage name and guild and put this into a new data frame. So for example in passage A, 4 eurytopic species where found of which 3 passed so 75% of Eurytopic species passed.

So the new data frame for passage A should look something like this:

| Passage Name | Guild | Passage % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Rheophilic | 100% |
| A | Eurytopic | 75% |

I have previously calculated this by hand for every passage in my dataset, however I feel like it can be much smoother done if calculated by R, this would also prevent mistakes made by me. I have previously tried methods like this post: (https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/30951617/how-to-count-and-calculate-percentages-for-two-columns-in-an-r-data-frame). However, this doesn't fully answer my question and I am too inexperienced with R to fix this by myself. So, if someone likes to teach me that would be greatly appreciated. I am also quite new to stack overflow so sorry if the formatting isn't perfect.

Answer (score 2):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    na.omit %>%
    group_by(`Passage Name`, Guild) %>%
    summarise(Passage% = 100 * mean(`Passage yes/no`))
```